# algorithm to add elements of a 2D array in the following format?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

**suppose any arbitrary array X[N][3] is (If N=3):**

```
18 7 6
23 10 27
20 9 14
```

**i need to add elements like this:**

```
18+7+6=31, 18+23+10+27=78, 18+23+20+9+14=84
```

**then i need to find the maximum value. In above case it is 84.** How should i approach this problem ? A pseudo code suited for C++ would be helpful.

***Update:***
for those who think i did not tried this problem i would like to say that i devoted whole yesterday to come up with solution and i got frustrated and asked here for help. I came up with the below code but that is wrong:

```
   for(int k=0; k<N; k++){
      for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(i<N-1-k){
            t=t+X[i][0];
        }
        else{
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                t=t+X[i][j];
                if(answer<t){
                answer=t;
                }
            }
        }
      }
      t=0;
    }

    cout<<answer;
```

Comment: an attempt from your side would be helpful. SO is not a "please write some code for me" service. What is the question?

Comment: "for those who think i did not tried this problem" - Nobody thinks that, at least not me. Nevertheless, you have to understand that in order to get help you will have to explain where exactly you got stuck and what prevents you from solving the problem. Even now I could criticize that you do not tell us in what way your current solution is wrong nor do you say how you know that it is wrong (e.g. providing expected and observed output would help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking for pseudo code below c# code fragment will help you. I dont know wheather you are asking for a optimized alg. or not but the code below is calculating all the possible values (it is not the optimum solution I mean)

```
        int[,] m = new int[3, 3] { { 18, 7, 6 }, { 23, 10, 27}, { 20, 9, 14 } };
        int max = Int32.MinValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            int firstColl = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < i+1; ++j)
            {
                firstColl += m[j, 0];
            }
            int value = firstColl + m[i, 1] + m[i, 2];
            if (max < value)
                max = value;
        }
```

Comment: `max` should be initialized to `MIN_INT` (or its C# counterpart) because you could get negative integers from the input.

Comment: @rerito yes i will keep that in mind. I just needed simple logic to solve the problem. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::accumulate` for that purpose:

```
int array[][3] = { {18, 7, 6}, {23, 10, 27}, {20, 9, 14} };
auto partial_sum = 0;
auto result = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(array), std::cend(array), std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    [&partial_sum](int result, auto const& subarray) {
        auto new_result = partial_sum
            + std::accumulate(std::cbegin(subarray), std::cend(subarray), 0);
        partial_sum += *std::cbegin(subarray);
        return std::max(new_result, result);
    });
std::cout << result << '\n';
```

A live demo on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63caeb240967c956).

Note that I use a C++14 feature: there is a generic lambda to avoid the hassle of specifying the subarray container type (so that the code works regardless of the container you use).

Interest of using non-member begin and end is to abstract ourselves from the chosen container.

A simpler loop based version:

```
#define N 3
int array[N][3] = { {18, 7, 6}, {23, 10, 27}, {20, 9, 14} };
int partial_sum = 0;
int result = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    int row_sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        row_sum += array[i][j];
    }
    result = std::max(row_sum + partial_sum, result);
    partial_sum += array[i][0];
}
```

Comment: sorry, but imho your code is a nice example of how supposedly modern C++ can be much less readable and understandable than some plain old-fashioned loops

Comment: @tobi303 I definitely get why you think that. Like for anything else, there are pros and cons. Since the question is tagged C++ I thought it would be interesting to demonstrate how to benefit from some genericity.

Answer (score -1):

```
int add = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
        add+=arr[i][0];
        sum = add;
        for(int j=1;j<n;j++){
            sum+=arr[i][j];
        }
        if(max<sum){
            max = sum;
        }
    }
    cout<<max;
```